# Ediff directories with remote path (and Prelude?)

Tags: tramp, ediff, remote

I need to compare from time to time the contents (source code) of a remote directory with a local one.  And I would like to mark for hiding those files/subdirs that are identical (that is, use the `=h` command).  But in the list of diff sessions, the remote files are marked as `*remote file*` instead of appearing the time stamp, and `=h` does simply nothing.

I found a hack in the web, to try to handle this situation (in fact, to handle tramp and ediff interaction).  The code is:

```
(defun ediff-listable-file (file-name)
  (let ((handler (find-file-name-handler file-name 'file-local-copy)))
    (or (null handler) (eq handler 'dired-handler-fn) (eq handler 'tramp-file-name-handler))))

(defun ediff-same-file-contents (f1 f2)
  "Return t if files F1 and F2 have identical contents."
  (if (and (not (file-directory-p f1))
           (not (file-directory-p f2)))
      (let ((res
         (apply 'call-process ediff-cmp-program nil nil nil
            (append ediff-cmp-options
                            (list (if (tramp-tramp-file-p f1)
                                      (tramp-handle-file-local-copy f1)
                                    f1)
                                  (if (tramp-tramp-file-p f2)
                                      (tramp-handle-file-local-copy f2)
                                    f2))))))
    (and (numberp res) (eq res 0)))))
```

The problem with this code is that with command `=h` I get now the error message `Symbol's function definition is void: tramp-handle-file-local-copy`, meaning that the mentioned function is not existing.

Could anybody please help me with this?  I'm using **GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8)** (with **Prelude** Emacs configuration).

Thanks!

### Update

As pointed out by the selected answer contributor, the problem is the **Prelude** environment.  I have tried to find out were to touch without generating a disaster, and I found that **Projectile** might be the problem.  But, after updating the **Prelude** configuration system (with a simple `git update` in `.emacs.d`), everything seems to work nicely, including the `ediff-directories` and the `=h` command.

Sorry, I shoud have tried that first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange. I can compare two directories (local and remote), after starting `emacs -Q`. In the ediff buffer it shows me `*remote file*`, but it shows all files also which can be hidden after calling `=h`. Btw, I call usually `=hx`, in order to hide the superfluous files immediately.

Maybe your environment is in the way? Have you tried it with `emacs -Q`? My Emacs version is

> GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.16.6)  of
>   2015-09-17 on lgw01-52, modified by Debian

Comment: Thanks, Michael, you were right: it is the Prelude configuration.  Now, I have to figure out why this does not work with Prelude...